# How can one estimate a new λ for a Poisson Distribution after changing circumstances?

Tags: bayesian, poisson-distribution, pymc

To fit the question to a problem lets say you have a store in a mall where the rate of customers visiting the store can be modelled as a Poisson Distribution where λ = 3.

Now lets say next month because of an effort by the mall to bring more shoppers to it the effective population of customers within the mall doubles. How would the store estimate the new λ that would result from this change?

If these new shoppers were expected to visit the store at the same rate should λ just be doubled to 6? If the rate of these new shoppers was expected to differ could I utilize Bayesian statistics to calculate a posterior distribution for the new shoppers and add it onto my already existing Poisson Distribution?

```
old_rate = 3
n_obs = 10,000
poisson_shoppers = np.random.poisson(old_rate, 10000)

# fit a pymc3 model to get the rate
basic_model = pm.Model()

with basic_model:
    lambda_prior = pm.Uniform('lambda_prior',1,4)

    #likelihood
    Y_obs = pm.Poisson('Y_obs',mu = lambda_prior, observed = poisson_shoppers)


with basic_model:
    trace = pm.sample(2000)
    pm.traceplot(trace)
    plt.show()
```

From the distribution generated could I just add up my counts for both distributions to then generate an estimate what the rate would be for the doubled population of shoppers?

If anything is to vague or needs further details please let me know and I will try to better explain or add them.

Comment: You can simply only use the new data for estimation if you know that the distribution has changed.

Comment: Alternatively, especially if the change is gradual, consider using exponential smoothing to update an estimate of the average number of customers. This can also incorporate seasonal fluctuations or trends. https://otexts.com/fpp3/expsmooth.html

Comment: If you're just hoping the advertising has doubled the population size so the rate goes from $\lambda$ to $2\lambda,$ then it might be a good idea to get fresh data to estimate $\lambda.$ However, if the Poisson rate is $\lambda = .2/hr$ and you're interested in a 2-hour time period, then just use $\lambda = 0.4/2hr.$